# Samsung Galaxy E5/S5 ADB

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have a question first: Do I have to root my Samsung Galaxy E5? I just bought it yesterday because I want to pursue my career in Android App Development, since my laptop is slow to handle AVD.

Next, I have spent like 3 hours for searching how to make my phone to be the emulator in my projects in Eclipse. I used to do this last year, but back then, my old phone was already rooted.

What have I tried:

1. Installed Android Studio and Eclipse (I though Android Studio would be faster so I installed it, I realize I should stick with Eclipse).
2. Installed SDK.
3. Installed Google Driver.
4. Windows 8.1 automatically installed the driver for my phone, that why when I plug it in my laptop, the CARD and Phone Memory Storage pops up!
5. I tried installing this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=LbAq6d2Du0U
6. I discovered my path to SDK, C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
   and then performed the command: adb devices
   it listed no device.

That's all. When I plug in my phone, there's no other options, just Media and Camera something. So, do I have to root it? I'm afraid that the warrant might be voided by rooting the phone.

Comment: did you activate the developer mode on your phone?

Comment: wow thanks Jibbo! I have activated it! Lol, I just had to tap 7 times the Build Number information! HOWEVER, I have checked all the necessary checkboxes in my Developer Options, still, I can't see my device when I run adb services :(

Comment: ok, now that the obvious is sorted out, I'd give a shot at directly installing samsung drivers.

Comment: thanks Jibbo.!!!! WOOOO!!! It works now. :) I'm debugging my hello world app via WiFi, I love it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install Samsung Drivers.

http://www.teamandroid.com/2015/04/05/download-samsung-galaxy-e5-usb-drivers/

Comment: thanks AC for giving me the link. :) I can now debug my hello world app via wifi. !!!! :)))) http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html